# Response.write javascript changes font size c#

Tags: c#

I have a response.write with script for popup, its working fine with the popup, but the page's fonts increase after getting the popup. how can I stop increasing the font automatically ??

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('SuccessFully Saved')</script>");
```

Comment: this is probably a side effect of appending tags to the DOM in a location that breaks it.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is highly unrecommended. If you want to pop an alert window, use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "myScript", "alert('SuccessFully Saved');", true);
```

Comment: even this one changes the font size

Comment: How the heck did you know what he was on about feom such a vague question? Genius.